# When dropping, the item jumps to the left upper corner

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, widget, qt-designer

i have three boxes with items. The third box is a workfield. When i drop an item from box 1 and 2 in the workfield box, the item jumps to the left corner. I think this is because the object self.workfield is instantiated from QListWidget(). QListWidget perhaps has an specefic alignment? Is it possible to disable that alignment to move freely a QListWidgetItem? If it is not possible, then i had the following solution in mind:

When dragging an item from box 1/box 2 and drop it in box 3. The item will change to an label. Label is free to move.

Hopefully you guys have some solution or feedback for me. Thanks in advance

```
import socket
import threading
import time
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QListWidget, QHBoxLayout, QListWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.started = False
        self.buttonStopThread = False
        self.paused = False

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(915, 674)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        #LOGICAL OPERATORS BOX 1------------------------------------------------------
        self.logicalOperatorsList = QListWidget()

        self.logicalOperatorsList.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.logicalOperatorsList.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.logicalOperatorsList.setDragEnabled(True)

        widgetLO1 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("bob.png"), "And")
        widgetLO2 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("OR.png"), "Or")
        widgetLO3 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("sorteerband.png"), "Sorteerband")

        self.logicalOperatorsList.addItem(widgetLO1)
        self.logicalOperatorsList.insertItem(2, widgetLO2)

        self.logicalOperatorsBox_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.logicalOperatorsBox_layout.addWidget(self.logicalOperatorsList)

        self.logicalOperatorsBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.logicalOperatorsBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 181, 201))
        self.logicalOperatorsBox.setLayout(self.logicalOperatorsBox_layout)
        self.logicalOperatorsBox.setObjectName("logicalOperatorsBox")

        #SENSORS BOX 2------------------------------------------------------
        self.sensorsWidgetList = QListWidget()

        self.sensorsWidgetList.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.sensorsWidgetList.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.sensorsWidgetList.setDragEnabled(True)

        widgetSensor1 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("metaaldetector.png"), "Metaaldetector")
        widgetSensor2 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("reflectiesensor.png"), "Reflectiesensor")
        widgetSensor3 = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("bewegingssensor.png"), "Bewegingssensor")

        self.sensorsWidgetList.insertItem(1, widgetSensor1)
        self.sensorsWidgetList.insertItem(2, widgetSensor2)

        self.sensorsBox_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.sensorsBox_layout.addWidget(self.sensorsWidgetList)

        self.sensorsBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.sensorsBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 181, 161))
        self.sensorsBox.setLayout(self.sensorsBox_layout)
        self.sensorsBox.setObjectName("sensorsBox")

        #WORKFIELD BOX 3------------------------------------------------------
        self.workfield = QListWidget()
        self.workfield.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.workfield.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.workfield.setDragEnabled(True)


        # workfieldItem = QListWidgetItem(QIcon("metaaldetector.png"), "Item")

        self.workfieldBox_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.workfieldBox_layout.addWidget(self.workfield)

        self.workfieldBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.workfieldBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 700, 600))
        self.workfieldBox.setLayout(self.workfieldBox_layout)
        self.workfieldBox.setObjectName("workfieldBox")

        #DELETE BUTTON---------------------------------------------------------
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.deleteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 450,100, 25))
        self.deleteButton.setObjectName("Delete_Button")
        self.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.removeItem)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 915, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")

        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")

        self.menuView = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuView.setObjectName("menuView")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")

        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")

        self.actionSave_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_as.setObjectName("actionSave_as")

        self.actionSave_as_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_as_2.setObjectName("actionSave_as_2")

        self.actionQuit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionQuit.setObjectName("actionQuit")

        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_as)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_as_2)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionQuit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuView.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        # self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.logicalOperatorsBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Box 1"))
        self.sensorsBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Box 2"))
        self.workfieldBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Workfield box"))
        self.deleteButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete Item"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuView.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_as_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save as"))
        self.actionQuit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Quit"))

    def removeItem(self):
        listItems = self.workfield.selectedItems()
        if not listItems: return
        for item in listItems:
            self.workfield.takeItem(self.workfield.row(item))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. When dropping items in a QListView, they are aligned based on the current contents: if the list is empty, they are on the top left (it's a list, after all), so the next question is unclear: first of all, the items do not "become" labels (so, what do you mean by that?) and then, if you're using the IconMode, they *are* free to be moved, that's the whole point of that mode.

Comment: @musicamante. thank for your response. Indeed, items do not become labels. So one of the solution i had in mind, was the following: "When drag an item from box 1 and drop it in box 3, the item will delete by itself and a label will be created automatically"

I set IconMode viewing for self.workfield. And you are right again. The items are freely to move in IconMode. But when i add a new item in box 3, all items will jump back to the upper left corner. What I want, is disabling the jumping of items in box 3. 

Hopefully my explanation is clear enough. Thanks in advance